# Magento 2 : Cookie Security: HTTPOnly not Set for customer id

Tags: magento2.2, customer-account, cookie

While Customer login in magento 2 system . We are setting cookie against Customer and cookie has been set but when are checking cookie in browser location where **HTTPONLY is** showing **False** that reason **Fortify security scan has raised security concern.**

More details please, find below attached screen-shot.

[image]

If anyone have idea then please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assumed that , you have set cookie in login controller.

When we are setting cookie for customer that if we are not sepcify **HTTPONly** value then by default it takes false.

If you want to make it true then you can set **true** value .

Please, check below code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Custom\OverrideCustomer\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data as CaptchaHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

/**
 * Login controller
 *
 * @method \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface getRequest()
 * @method \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http getResponse()
 */
class Login extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    protected $customTool;
    protected $captchaHelper;

     const KEY_HTTP_ONLY = 'http_only';

    /**
     * Initialize Login controller
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $helper,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Custom\OverrideCustomer\Helper\CustomTool $customTool,
        CaptchaHelper $captchaHelper,
            CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
            CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
            SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customTool = $customTool;
        $this->captchaHelper = $captchaHelper;
         $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Login registered users and initiate a session.
     *
     * Expects a POST. ex for JSON {"username":"user@magento.com", "password":"userpassword"}
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $credentials = null;
        $httpBadRequestCode = 400;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        try {
            $credentials = $this->helper->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $resultRaw->setHttpResponseCode($httpBadRequestCode);
        }
        if (!$credentials || $this->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'POST' || !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $resultRaw->setHttpResponseCode($httpBadRequestCode);
        }
        $response = [
            'errors' => false,
            'message' => __('Login successful.')
        ];


        try {
            $check  = $this->checkCaptcha();
            if ($check != "") {
                $response = [
                        'errors' => true,
                        'message' => 'Invalid Captcha'
                    ];
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                return $resultJson->setData($response);
            }
            /*
                Start :: Password Encryption
            */
            $password_array         = $this->customTool->passwordEncrypt($credentials['password']);
            if ($password_array['status'] == 'failure') {
                $response = [
                    'errors' => true,
                    'message' => $password_array['msg']
                ];
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                return $resultJson->setData($response);
            } else {
                $password           = $password_array['pwd'];
            }
            /*
                END  ::  Password Encryption
            */
            $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
            $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($credentials['username']);
            if (!$customer->getId()) {
                $response = [
                    'errors' => true,
                    'message' => 'There is no registered user with that email address. Please try again.'
                ];
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                return $resultJson->setData($response);
            }
            $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate(
                $credentials['username'],
                $password
            );
            $cookietime = time() + (86400 * 30);
            $this->setCookies($customer->getId(),$cookietime);
            $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $this->customerSession->regenerateId();   
        } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => true,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ];
        } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => true,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => true,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ];
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }

    public function checkCaptcha()
    {
        $formId = 'user_login_popup';
        $flag   = "";
        $captchaModel = $this->captchaHelper->getCaptcha($formId);
        $loginParams = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
        $login = isset($loginParams->username)
            ? $loginParams->username
            : null;
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
            $word = $this->resolve($this->getRequest(), $formId);
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($word)) {
                $flag   = "Invalid Captcha";
            }
        }
        $captchaModel->logAttempt($loginParams->username);
        return $flag;
    }

    /**
     * Get Captcha String
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param string $formId
     * @return string
     */
    public function resolve(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParamsObj = json_decode($request->getContent());
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($captchaParamsObj);return false;
        $captchaParams = get_object_vars($captchaParamsObj);
        $fieldName = (string)\Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE;

        return isset($captchaParams[$fieldName.'['.$formId.']']) ? $captchaParams[$fieldName.'['.$formId.']'] : '';
    }
    public function setCookies($customerId, $cookietime) {
        $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
                ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                ->setDuration($cookietime)
                ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
                ->setHttpOnly(true)// TO Set HTTPOnly True
                ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
                'gs_uid', $customerId, $metadata
        );
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you some extend.

Thanks!